# failed to authenticate multiple user in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-users

I have multiple user models in my Django app, one for `OLAROOM` and the other one for `REALTOR`. As you can see, everything is working successfully, but when I try to authenticate them and redirect them based on their role, it does not work. The authentication is working fine, but instead of redirecting the `Olaroom` user to the Rooms page, it is redirecting me to the `Realtor_Dashboard`, and the user role isn't a Realtor. Using the form below, the user is created based on what is defined in the save function. However, when I try to authenticate them and redirect the user to the page based on their role, it doesn't work, and I'm using the same method, something like this: `user.Role.REALTOR` and `user.Role.OLAROOM`. How can I solve this problem please?

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.Role.REALTOR:
                    auth_login(request, user)
                    return redirect('Realtor_Dashboard')
                elif user.Role.OLAROOM:
                    auth_login(request, user)
                    return redirect('Rooms')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Invalid Creadentials')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()        
    return render(request, 'Login/login.html', {'form':form})
```

**User Models**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    class Role(models.TextChoices):
        ADMIN = "ADMIN", 'Admin'
        REALTOR = "REALTOR", 'Realtor'
        OLAROOM = "OLAROOM", 'Olaroom'
    
    base_role = Role.ADMIN

    role = models.CharField(max_length=225, choices=Role.choices)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.role = self.base_role
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)


class OlaroomsManger(BaseUserManager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        results = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return results.filter(role=User.Role.OLAROOM)

class Olaroom(User):
    base_role = User.Role.OLAROOM

    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    country = CountryField()

    olaroom = OlaroomsManger()

    def welcome(self):
        return "Only for Olaroom"

class RealtorManger(BaseUserManager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        results = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return results.filter(role=User.Role.REALTOR)

class Realtor(User):

    base_role = User.Role.REALTOR
    address = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    country = CountryField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length=225)

    realtor = RealtorManger()

    def welcome(self):
        return "Only for Realtor"
```

**forms**:

```
class OlaroomSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = Olaroom
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'company_name', 'address', 'phone_number', 'country']

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super().save(commit=False)
            user.Role.OLAROOM
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user

class RealtorSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = Realtor
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'phone_number', 'country', 'state']

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super().save(commit=False)
            user.Role.REALTOR
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user
```

Comment: `user.Role.OLAROOM` what are you trying to do with this in SignUpForm? Also why not to use models with OneToOne fields for each type of User&

Comment: @Alex Using `user.Role.OLAROOM`, it means this user is a `OLAROOM` user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue i'm facing is related to how i'm checking the user's role and trying to redirect them after authentication. In my code, i'm checking `user.Role.REALTOR` and `user.Role.OLAROOM`, but this is not the correct way to check the user's role based on my models.

Instead, I should check the role attribute of the user instance to determine their role and redirect accordingly.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.role == User.Role.REALTOR:
                    auth_login(request, user)
                    return redirect('Realtor_Dashboard')
                elif user.role == User.Role.OLAROOM:
                    auth_login(request, user)
                    return redirect('Rooms')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()        
    return render(request, 'Login/login.html', {'form': form})
```

In this updated code, Instead of using `user.Role.REALTOR` or `user.Role.OLAROOM`, I'm using `user.role == User.Role.REALTOR` and `user.role == User.Role.OLAROOM` which means: If the user's role is `REALTOR`, it logs in the user using auth_login and redirects to a `Realtor_Dashboard` page. If the user role is `OLAROOM`, it logs in the user and redirects to a `Rooms` page.